# How to install .NET Portable in Docker?

Tags: .net, docker

I am using a C# project that targets  .NET Portable 4.5. Everything compiles OK on my computer, but once I try to convert it to a Docker image, the .NET Portable libraries are missing (?)

The error that I get in compilation is:
`error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for .NETPortable,Version=v4.5 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application.`

I tried to use the Docker script at [microsoft/dotnet-framework-docker](https://github.com/microsoft/dotnet-framework-docker/blob/main/src/sdk/4.8/windowsservercore-ltsc2019/Dockerfile) and it installed everything via `Visual Studio installation from command line` but .NET Portable installation is still missing :(

Here are parameters that I am running:

```
...
    && start /w vs_BuildTools ^ `
        --add Microsoft.Component.ClickOnce.MSBuild ^ `
        --add Microsoft.Net.Component.4.5.TargetingPack ^ `
        --add Microsoft.Net.Component.4.5.SDK ^ `
        --add Microsoft.Net.Component.4.6.2.TargetingPack ^ `
        --add Microsoft.Net.Component.4.6.2.SDK ^ `
        --add Microsoft.Net.Component.4.7.TargetingPack ^ `
        --add Microsoft.Net.Component.4.7.SDK ^ `
        --add Microsoft.Net.Component.4.7.1.TargetingPack ^ `
        --add Microsoft.Net.Component.4.8.SDK ^ `
        --add Microsoft.Net.Component.4.8.TargetingPack ^ `
        --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.PortableLibrary ^ `
        --add Microsoft.NetCore.Component.Runtime.3.1 ^ `
        --add Microsoft.NetCore.Component.Runtime.5.0 ^ `
        --add Microsoft.NetCore.Component.Runtime.6.0 ^ `
        --add Microsoft.NetCore.Component.SDK ^ `
        --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.NuGet.BuildTools ^ `
        --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.WebDeploy ^ `
        --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BuildTools.ComponentGroup ^ `
        --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.MSBuildTools ^ `
        --quiet --norestart --nocache --wait `
...
```

Here is on my machine:

```
    Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d----          16/02/2022    10:43                v4.0
d----          16/02/2022    10:43                v4.5
d----          16/02/2022    10:43                v4.6
d----          16/02/2022    10:43                v5.0
```

and this folder: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable` is missing inside Docker.

**How I could install .NET Portable into Docker container ?**

Answer (score 0):

It seems that root cause of the problem is that [microsoft/dotnet-framework-docker](https://github.com/microsoft/dotnet-framework-docker/blob/main/src/sdk/4.8/windowsservercore-ltsc2019/Dockerfile) start from:

```
ARG REPO=mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/runtime
FROM $REPO:4.8-20220210-windowsservercore-ltsc2019
```

and it seems that .NET Portable could not be installer at `Windows Server Core 2019` :( :(   I changed this line to:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows:1809-amd64
```

and install .NET Portable with Chocolatley:  [Portable Library Tools 2
10.0.50828.20180323](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/portable-library-tools-2) and now everything installed into Docker container the same as in my computer